# MongoDB Auto Increment ID with Golang mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, auto-increment, mongo-go

Based on the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo?tab=doc), `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` doesn't seem to provide a way to auto-increment ID when it is upserting a document that has not provided an ID.

```
    type Document struct {
        ID             int    `bson:"_id"`
        Foo            string `bson:"foo"`
    }

    document := &Document{Foo: "test"}

    filter := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$eq": document.ID}}
    update := bson.M{"$set": document}

    res, err := mongoClient.Database(dbName).
        Collection(collectionName).
        UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update,
            options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
```

In the code example above, ID will be defaulted to the zero value of int, which is `0`, and will be persisted in MongoDB as `{"_id":0,"foo":"test"}`.

Is there a clean way for auto-incrementing ID when ID is not provided using `mongo-driver`, without doing the logic of tracking the last ID myself? Say for example there are already 5 documents in the DB, then running the code above will persist `{"_id":6,"foo":"test"}` when ID is not provided.

Comment: If you are not dependent on the increment of values itself, Use a UUID for uniqueness. Its very common in go.

Comment: The autocremented ID's are actually very important for backward compatibility, but can't find a good solution with `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` without implementing much logic myself.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use the default ObjectID ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the same problem, the solution that i thought was to define the **Document** struct without ID:

```
type Document struct {
    Foo string `bson:"foo"`
}
```

Then, if an **InsertOne** operation is executed using the mongo-driver:

```
res, err := mongoClient.Database(dbName).Collection(collectionName).InsertOne(ctx, document)
```

The **_id** will be created automatically in the database(You can repeat the **InsertOne** operation several times and new **_id**s will appear).

The mongodb documentation explains this behaviour: *"If the document does not specify an _id field, then mongod will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting."* (You can read more details in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#db.collection.insertOne)

In case that you need the new created **_id** for some reason, you can use the following snippet as a reference to retrieve it:

```
fmt.Println("New Document created with mongodb _id: " + res.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID).Hex())
```

(**primitive.ObjectID** is related with this: import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive")

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the following:

```
    type Document struct {
        ID             int    `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Foo            string `bson:"foo"`
    }
```